# How to run Nauty by Sage?

Tags: sage

I am very new with both Sage and Nulty (http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/). I use Windows8. So I run Sage by Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager. I came to know that Nauty can be used by Sage. But how?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you should be able to run `install_package('nauty')` in the Sage command line (or even in the notebook), or `sage -i nauty` instead of just `sage`.  Then there are various ways to invoke it, such as seen [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html#sage.graphs.graph_generators.GraphGenerators.nauty_geng).

However, there are two (hopefully minor) issues.

1. Nauty has a GPL-incompatible license. So just be aware of that.  This is why it cannot be distributed directly with Sage.
2. You will need a compiler to actually install it.  I don't know if the virtual machine provides this.  See what `which gcc` does in the command line of the virtual machine.